# Data type doesn't work inside function argument

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have this data type:

```
data Zinf = NegInf | Z Integer | PosInf deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

It is also `Num`, since all necessary operations are defined. When I type for example `PosInf + 1`, the interpret returns `PosInf`.

Now I derive yet another data type:

```
data Interval = Simple Integer | Complicated Zinf Zinf deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now, since Zinf is also `Num`, I can write down the following:

```
(Z 3) + 4
```

and I get

```
(Z 7)
```

I can also test

```
(Z 3) + 6 == 9
```

and the interpret returns `True`.

I can also write `Complicated 3 (6*7)` to get `Complicated (Z 3) (Z 42)`.

Finally, I create a tree with these "Interval" data types:

```
data BinTree a = Empty | Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
type ITree = BinTree Interval
```

Now, when I try to write this function:

```
moveBy :: ITree -> Integer -> ITree
moveBy Empty _ = Empty
moveBy (Node (Simple a) l r) i = (Node (Simple (a+i)) (moveBy l i) (moveBy r i))
moveBy (Node (Complicated a b) l r) i = (Node ( Complicated (a + i) (b + i) ) (moveBy l i) (moveBy r i))
```

it produces the following error:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Zinf' with actual type `Integer'                                                         
* In the second argument of `(+)', namely `i'                                                                             
In the second argument of `Complicated', namely `(b + i)'                                                                     
In the first argument of `Node', namely `(Complicated (a + i) (b + i))'
```

How come? `b` should be of type `Zinf`, `b+i` again of type `Zinf`, since `i` is `Integer`. And `Complicated` expects exactly this kind of argument.

Comment: As the error message says, `b` in that expression is of type `Zinf`, while `i` is an `Integer`. You can't use the `(+)` function on two different types. (It only appeared to work with integer literals because, due to your `Num` instance for `Zinf`, the "integer" literals could be interpreted as `Zinf` values. But you can't convert an actual integer to a `Zinf`, or vice versa, without an explicit conversion function.)

Comment: What do you suggest then, please? This confuses me a lot.

Comment: Since it appears that you need a `Zinf` here, you can just make the `Integer` a `Zinf` by using the `Z` constructor: `Complicated (a + Z i) (b + Z i)` (apologies if I've made a silly mistake, I've not tried it to see if it compiles)

Comment: @RobinZigmond These sentences should probably live in an answer, not as comments!

Comment: @DanielWagner true, and I did consider it, I'm definitely guilty of too often writing in a comment what could be an answer. In my defence, often, as here, I'm not totally certain what the OP is asking or what they are confused by, and I prefer not to write an answer unless I'm sure it will shed light on the OP's actual question. (But on reflection it's a poor excuse in this case.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now, since Zinf is also Num, I can write down the following:
>
> ```
> (Z 3) + 4
> ```

Yes, but it's important that `(+)` has in this case *not* the type `Zinf -> Integer -> Zinf`, as it may seem. You may be thinking `4` has type integer there, but it doesn't: it actually has type `Zinf`. This is surprising since `3` *does* have type integer!

What's going on: Haskell number literals are polymorphic.

```
Prelude> :t 1
1 :: Num p => p
```

So, a number literal can have type `Integer` or `Float` or indeed `Zinf`, depending on what the context demands. In `(Z 3) + 4` this is `Zinf` for `4`, so `4` has type `Zinf` there. Great!

However, this does not work in `Simple (a+i)`, because there the type of `i` is fixed by the signature / context to be `Integer`. Therefore you can't add it to a `Zinf`.

What you can do however: any `Integer` value can be “upgraded” into a polymorphic number (like number literals) by wrapping it<sup>†</sup> in `fromInteger`. So, what you want there is

```
moveBy (...) i = (Node (Simple (a + fromInteger i)) (...) (...)
```

or equivalently `Simple (a + Z i)`.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually what's going on with number literals is that they also just wrap the “plain” integer literal in `fromInteger`, to make it polymorphic.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

When you write

```
Z 3 + 4
```

it does not mean

```
Z 3 + (4 :: Integer)
```

but

```
Z 3 + (4 :: Zinf)
```

and uses `fromInteger :: Integer -> Zinf` (implemented by you in your `Num` instance) to interpret the `4` as a `Zinf`. Indeed, addition must always be between two values of the same type -- say, two `Zinf`s, or two `Integer`s -- never between a `Zinf` and an `Integer`.

You may modify your `moveBy` to take a `Zinf` argument, so that addition is fine:

```
moveBy :: ITree -> Zinf -> ITree
-- implementation as in the question
```

Or you may convert the `Integer` given to `moveBy` to a `Zinf` in the same way as is being implicitly done when you write `Z 3 + 4`:

```
moveBy :: -- as in the question
moveBy (Node (Simple a) l r) i = Node (Simple (a+fromInteger i)) (moveBy l i) (moveBy r i)
-- and similarly for the Complicated case
```